# LocalStorage not working inside WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, local-storage

I have a table that looks like this

`<table>
<tr>
<td class="score"><input type="text" maxlength="3" name="%s" class="auto-save"></td>
<td class="score"><input type="text" maxlength="3" name="%s" class="auto-save"></td>
</tr>
<table>`

The code above is generated by PHP code that looks like this 
`return sprintf( '<input %s name="%s" value="%s" class="auto-save" />'`

Then I have this piece of js code for saving/clearing form data - Credit https://github.com/medabida/savy

savy.js - https://github.com/medabida/savy/blob/master/savy.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../savy.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

//$('.auto-save').savy('load') --> can be used without callback
$('.auto-save').savy('load',function(){
console.log("All data from savy are loaded");
});

function dstry(){
//$('.auto-save').savy('destroy') --> can be used without callback
$('.auto-save').savy('destroy',function(){
console.log("All data from savy are Destroyed");
window.location.reload();
});
}
</script>
```

I have added the js files to my theme folder. The name attribute in the table td is the unique identifier, i changed the id in savy.js to accomodate the name attribute (I didn't want to use id because the name attribute is autogenerated and unique) When i add a post, the contents of the new td name value are auto-incremented e.g previous is name="_name_43" the new becomes name="_name_44". Having noted that the value in name attribute is not hard-corded, here is the php code that auto generates it. `return sprintf( '<input %s name="%s" value="%s" class="auto-save" />'`

My manipulated savy.js looks like so

```
<script>(function($) {
$.fn.savy = function(order,fn) {
const sv = "savy-";
if (order == "load") {
$(this).each(function() {
if ($(this).is(":radio")) {
      if(localStorage.getItem(sv+$(this).attr("name"))){
        if (localStorage.getItem(sv+$(this).attr("name")) == this.name) {
          this.checked = true;
        }else{
          this.checked = false
        }
      }
      $(this).change(function() {
        localStorage.setItem(sv+$(this).attr("name"), this.name);
      });
    }else if($(this).is(":checkbox")){
      if(localStorage.getItem(sv+this.name)){
        this.checked = (localStorage.getItem(sv+this.name) == "1" ? true : false);
      }
      $(this).change(function() {
        localStorage.setItem(sv+this.name, (this.checked ? "1" : "0"));
      });
    }else if($(this).is("input") || $(this).is("textarea")) {
      if(localStorage.getItem(sv+this.name)){
        this.value = localStorage.getItem(sv+this.name);
      }
      $(this).keyup(function() {
        localStorage.setItem(sv+this.name, this.value);
      });
    }else if($(this).is("select")) {
      if ($(this).is("[multiple]")) {
        if(localStorage.getItem(sv+this.name)){
          $(this).val(localStorage.getItem(sv+this.name).split(","));
        }else{
          localStorage.setItem(sv+this.name, $(this).val());
        }
        $(this).change(function() {
          localStorage.setItem(sv+this.name, $(this).val());
        });
      }else{
        if(localStorage.getItem(sv+this.name)){
          $(this).val(localStorage.getItem("savy-"+this.name));
        }else{
          localStorage.setItem(sv+this.name, $(this).val());
        }
        $(this).change(function() {
          localStorage.setItem(sv+this.name, $(this).val());
        });
      }

    }
  });
  if ($.isFunction(fn)){fn();}
}else if (order == "destroy") {
  $(this).each(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem(sv+this.name)){
      localStorage.removeItem(sv+this.name)
    }
  });
  if ($.isFunction(fn)){fn();}
}else{
  console.error("savy action not defined please use $('.classname').savy('load') to trigger savy to save all inputs")
}  };})(jQuery);</script>
```

The code is working well when I run from my desktop text editor, but in all manner of ways, I can't get it to work inside WordPress. What could I be doing wrong? I am not complete beginner in programming but willing to get dirty. Please help me figure out my way.

Comment: Just to exclude it as the possible reason, jQuery and `savy.js` are properly linked and you don't get errors in the console?

Comment: No errors with those

Comment: Right, next step is basic debugging. Use `console.log(...)` to see which parts are called (or not) and where exactly things go wrong.